# $uibModal keeping changes even after closed

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate an `uibModal` into my application which will allow users to change settings. My problem is that if I make changes to the settings and then close the modal without saving, the changes are still present when I open the modal back up.

I have my normal controller to open the modal (everything sits on `$scope`):

```
            var settings = $scope.site.smartboard_settings;


            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/modals/modal.smartboard.settings.tpl.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
                resolve: {
                    Settings: function() {
                        return settings;
                    }
                },
                controller: 'EditSmartboardSettingsModalController',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'
            });
```

And I have my modal controller:

```
.controller( 'EditSmartboardSettingsModalController',
    function( $uibModalInstance, $timeout, Settings ) {


        var $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.settings = Settings;
        $ctrl.submitted = false;



        $ctrl.submitForm = function( isValid ) {
        ...
        ...
```

So I open the modal and change a setting. I then close the modal and re-open it and the changed setting is still modified.

I understand it must have something to do with `$scope`, however, I thought that by passing in `settings` and using `controllerAs` then I shouldn't be modifying anything on the `$scope`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularjs never copes objects itself when you pass params -- this would be very expensive. In this concret situaton you should copy settng in modal controller e.g.:

```
$ctrl.settings = angular.copy(Settings);
```

Comment: Thanks @Petr, that certainly has resolved my issue. So realistically, is this how I should be treating all of my modal instances?

Comment: @Riples quite often. In some cases when you dont want to copy all and/or want to modify something you can copy manually: $ctrl.settings = {prop: Settings.prop, prop2: Settings.prop2.toUpperCase(), ...}